# How to remove margin from gauge chart in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have setup a solidgauge chart from Highcharts, my problem seems to be when this is rendered, there is a large white space at the top of the chart. I wish to remove this to allow me to place it in the middle of the div is resides in.

See photograph displaying how it currently renders:

[image]

See my snipped recreated below:

```js
var gaugeOptions = {

    chart: {
        type: 'solidgauge', 
        animation: true,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      },
  
    title: null,
  
    pane: {
        center: ['50%', '85%'],
        size: '100%',
        startAngle: -90,
        endAngle: 90,
        background: {
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
            innerRadius: '60%',
            outerRadius: '100%',
            shape: 'arc'
        }
    },
  
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false
    },
  
    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
    plotBands: {
        from: 70,
        to: 71,
        color: '#DF5353',
        thickness: '45%',
        outerRadius: '105%'
    },
      stops: [
        [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
        [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
        [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
      ],
      lineWidth: 0,
      minorTickInterval: null,
      tickAmount: 2,
      title: {
        y: -70
      },
      labels: {
        y: 16
      }
    },
  
    plotOptions: {
      solidgauge: {
        dataLabels: {
          y: 5,
          borderWidth: 0,
          useHTML: true
        }
      }
    }
  };
  
  // The speed gauge
  var chartSpeed = Highcharts.chart('plate-count-gauge-dry-side', Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      title: {
        text: 'Speed'
      }
    },
  
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
  
    series: [{
      name: 'Speed',
      data: [80],
      dataLabels: {
        format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
          ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y}</span><br/>' +
          '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">km/h</span></div>'
      },
      tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' km/h'
      }
    }]
  
  }));
  
  // Bring life to the dials
  setInterval(function() {
    // Speed
    var point,
      newVal,
      inc;
  
    if (chartSpeed) {
      point = chartSpeed.series[0].points[0];
      inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 100);
      newVal = point.y + inc;
  
      if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 100) {
        newVal = point.y - inc;
      }
  
      point.update(newVal);
    }
  }, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>

<div id="plate-count-gauge-dry-side" class="m-auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It kinda depends on your use case, but the cause of the issue is the positioning of the pane. Specifically the `center` property. If you change it to `center: ['50%', '50%']` it will be rendered on top of the container.

Answer (score 0):

This size is because chart is adapt for the whole circle, try to positioning using `center` property.

```
pane: {
  ...,
  center: ['50%', '100%']
},

plotOptions: {
  series: {
    ...,
    center: ['50%', '115%']
  },
  ...
}
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t0mb4xcz/